# Unix daemon starts before network dependency is up

Tags: unix, daemon, start-stop-daemon

I am trying to create a daemon that is started automatically during the boot-up. It depends on the network, local fs and remote fs services. I believe I have done everything to indicate these dependencies and I expect the daemon to be started after the network daemons are up and running. But when I look into my logs I see that my daemon S1 is consistently starting before the network daemon is available.

The following is the init information in my S1.sh script located in /etc/init.d:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: My S1 Service
# Required-Start: $local_fs $network $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:  $local_fs $network $remote_fs
# Default-Start:  2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:   0 1 6
# Short-Description: start S1 Service
# Description:  S1 Service
### END INIT INFO
```

And the following are my entries in the rc directories:

```
rc0.d:<br/>
K20S1_Service.sh -> ../init.d/S1.sh

rc1.d:<br/>
K20S1_Service.sh -> ../init.d/S1.sh

rc2.d:<br/>
S98S1_Service.sh -> ../init.d/S1.sh

rc3.d:<br/>
S98S1_Service.sh -> ../init.d/S1.sh

rc4.d:<br/>
S98S1_Service.sh -> ../init.d/S1.sh

rc5.d:<br/>
S98S1_Service.sh -> ../init.d/S1.sh

rc6.d:<br/>
K20S1_Service.sh -> ../init.d/S1.sh
```

Is there anything more I have to do or am I doing anything wrong to make sure that my service/daemon is started after the network services/daemons are available? Platform is Linux Mint 14.

Comment: I am reading up on upstart but I really like to know whats wrong with my current scripts and daemon startup.